# Is there an operator/function that will take any number, like e.g. $43$, and make it $4.3$, $f(x) = 1 \le y < 10$?

Tags: functions, notation

It will basically take any real number $x$ and make so that it is a new number, $1 \le y < 10$, the first digit being in front of the decimal point, and the rest of the digits behind the decimal point. One way to do this is this:

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{10^{d(x)-1}}$$

Where $d(x)$ is equal to the number of digits in $x$. Not sure if $d(x)$ is common notation however.

Comment: You can find the number of digits in a number using logarithms and rounding

Comment: @TomKern I know of a method like what you speak of, but it only works for integers. Are there methods that work for the reals as well?

Comment: More directly: $$f(x) = x \times 10^{-\left\lfloor \log_{(10)} x \right\rfloor}$$ where the exponent is using the floor function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $d(x)$ function you're looking for is d(x)=floor(log(x))+1

This does not correctly give you the number of digits for decimal numbers, but when you plug into your formula above for $f(x)$, still gives you the correct answer:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jyrhqvi8ky